# Problem extracting tar.gz files, tar: Conflicting compression options

Tags: 20.04, tar

```
tar -zjvf /home/alan/Downloads/gramps-5.1.3.tar.gz
```

I receive error

```
tar: Conflicting compression options
```

I am new to 20.04 and unfamiliar to tar.gz, but I think that it has to do with `-zjvf`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at what `man tar` has to say on the topic...

> ```
>   -j, --bzip2
>         Filter the archive through bzip2(1).
>
>   -z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip
>         Filter the archive through gzip(1).
> ```

See the conflict? Pick one and get rid of the other.

I recommend `-z` for a .gz file.

Answer (score 1):

For your information, you may not need to extract this archive at all.

The GRAMPS (*Genealogical research program*) is [packaged for all Ubuntu releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gramps). You can install 5.1.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the repository by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install gramps
```